# Significato di "cavo a motore" in questa frase

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Le otto montagne*, di Paolo Cognetti, ho letto questa frase (grassetto mio):

> Mio padre detestava gli sciatori, non voleva saperne di mischiarsi a loro: trovava qualcosa di offensivo nel gioco di scendere per la montagna senza la fatica di salirci, lungo un pendio spianato dalle ruspe e attrezzato con un **cavo a motore**.

Non riesco a capire il significato di "cavo a motore": me lo potreste spiegare?

Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000938.jpg) e sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cavo2/) ho visto diverse accezioni di "cavo" come "fune", ma non ho trovato l'espressione "cavo a motore".

Answer (score 2):

Per cavo si intende sicuramente una fune, come hai trovato tu nel vocabolario; *cavo a motore* secondo me sta ad indicare un argano motorizzato o, in modo più specifico, l'argano di un impianto di [skilift](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skilift)

Answer (score 2):

> cavo a motore

Sovente in italiano si usa la particella "a", in modo certe volte improprio, per indicare il funzionamento. Se sostituisci la particella `a` con la frase "che funziona con", capisci bene, per esempio:

barca a remi
locomotiva a vapore
motore a gasolio
stufa a legna
argano a molla
telefono a gettoni
veicolo a pedali
computer a 32 bit
strumento a percussione (o ad arco, a fiato...)

...e moltissimi altri. Ho accennato all'uso improprio: ora mi viene in mente il "tiro alla fune" (un gioco, una gara) che sarebbe più carino se fosse "tiro della fune"; ci sono molti francesismi costruiti così, che alcuni (fra cui io) definiscono brutti (il discorso è lungo).

Per la tua domanda specifica, il cavo si riferisce al cavo che traina i seggiolini degli impianti di risalita. È la prima volta che incontro "cavo a motore", potrei dire che in italiano non esiste, non come esiste per esempio "barca a remi". Perché la locuzione di per sé è troppo generica e anche un po' stridente: una macchina dotata di un cavo e di un motore (ce ne sono molte) ha generalmente un nome più appropriato che ne indica lo scopo, il cavo da solo è inutile. Ma c'è la spiegazione: io colgo nel testo il risentimento di questa persona, che degrada l'impianto di risalita (che è secondo me un'opera d'ingegneria non banale) a un semplice cavo trainato da un motore.